# Как удалить тег <a> с содержимым из строки в PHP?

Tags: php

Как удалить тег  с содержимым из строки в PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, тогда можешь использовать регулярные выражения

`<a([\s\S]+)?>([\s\S]+)?<\/a>`

То есть совпадения будут, такие как:

`<a></a>`

`<a href="somehref"></a>`

`<a href="somehref">asdasd</a>`

`<a>asdasd</a>`

`\s` - находит пробельные символы, а также переносы, эквивалентен `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`

`\S` - делает все тоже самое, только наоборот, находит все кроме пробельных символов

`()` - группируешь

`?` - добавляешь, исключение, на то, что это может быть, а может и не быть, потому что вопрос не совсем понятен

Объединяем с `php`

```
<?php

$string = 'some string <a>asdasd</a> ';
$pattern = '/<a([\s\S]+)?>([\s\S]+)?<\/a>/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $string); // some string
```

Comment: лукас за старание и оформление)

Comment: Это работает криво.

Answer (score 0):

`$text = '1<p></p><div><a><a href="">2</a>';`

`$text= strip_tags($text);` - Удалить все теги

`$text= strip_tags($text, '<p>');` - Удалить все теги, кроме `<p>`

`$text = preg_replace('/<(p|a).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>/ism', '$2', $text);` - удалить `<p>` и `<a>`

`$text = preg_replace('/<(p|a).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>/ism', '', $text);` - тоже самое что и выше, но вместе с содержимым.

Comment: вот это не плохо